# Select only one character by mouse in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How can I enable to select only one character by mouse in Visual Studio 2013?

It's comfortable after a typo to select it by mouse, but here I must select at least two or three characters to make a selection for editing.

edit:
to be clear let's say the cursor is already far away from that typo and VS have default setting with added opencv. Still it won't select only one character, I must click, hold, move for at least three to make a selection (or more rows).

Comment: Why would you ever need to select a single character with the mouse at all? It's easier just to hit backspace or Shift-Arrow than it is to move your hand to the mouse and select it.

Comment: Click once, press backspace, type new character.

Answer (score 0):

It's already enabled and you shouldn't modify anything. Visual Studio does not interfere with mouse settings and you should be able to use it just like you would with any other text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is annoying!

To select a single character

- double click it with the left mouse.

If the character is in a word, unfortunately,

- you will have to click in front of the character, then holding **shift** select past the character.

It's a pity you only got rude responses. 
Not a very good solution but will still help your workflow if you are used to selecting a single character via the mouse :)